# Strange "sh" behaviour

Tags: linux, bash, sh, angstrom-linux

I am developing an application on Beaglebone board with Angstrom distrubition fo Linux.I faced an interesting problem.

When I execute :

```
sh /home/root/Desktop/BBTCP/out/vehicleDetect 192.168.10.29
```

in terminal it says

```
/home/root/Desktop/BBTCP/out/vehicleDetect:     /home/root/Desktop/BBTCP/out/vehicleDetect:         cannot execute binary file
```

But when i execute

```
cd /home/root/Desktop/BBTCP/
```

and

```
sh out/vehicleDetect 192.168.10.29
```

it starts working??

What is the reason and why I can't run tha application with first configuration?

I think it is about the difference between ./ and sh. What are the differences?

Comment: *think it is about the difference between ./ and sh*: but both your examples use `sh`, neither uses `./`.

Comment: What does "which sh" give in each directory, and what does "file path/to/vehicleDetect" give?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first guess would be that one of the folders in the path `/home/root/Desktop/BBTCP` is a link. If `vehicleDetect` is a script and it invokes itself recursively, then this link might be confusing it.

If that's not the case, try `sh -x /home/root/Desktop/BBTCP/out/vehicleDetect` and see what that prints.

Lastly, check what's in the folder `/home/root/Desktop/BBTCP`. There might be an executable `sh` in there. If your path contains `.`, a different shell might be executed.

Comment: I have found the solution, vehicledetect is not a script, it is an executable binary. so using sh is not true way. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `/home/root/Desktop/BBTCP/out/vehicleDetect` is invoking a binary file (an executable) that was built on a different architecture.

The main difference between `sh` and `./` is that `./` will attempt to execute the file itself as an executable, whereas `sh` will do that for you.  It could be that there is a weird magic number at the start of the file, but you would expect `sh` to complain about that.

Best guess though it is a `#!` line at the start of the file which either contains invalid characters or refers to a strange file.  Did you, for example, bring this script file from another operating system (like Windows) that has different line endings?  I have seen similar effects when text file scripts have not been converted but just copied.  Maybe you downloaded it in a strange format?

Check with `od -xc /home/root/Desktop/BBTCP/out/vehicleDetect` and look at the first line.